# get sequence value using EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am trying to reuse some parts of the code. In my `DbContext`, I have created the following method to return a sequence value by passing a sequence parameter (which is of enum type).

```
public async Task<long> GetSequenceValue(SequenceList sequenceList)
{
    var query = this.Database.SqlQuery<int>($"Select {sequenceList}.NextVal From Dual ");

    var result = query.ToList();

    return result.Any() ? result.First() : 0;
}
```

Because the `FormattableString` type is being converted to a parameter (I think), I am unable to get the result. I get this error instead:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005):
> ORA-22806: not an object or REF

Comment: Do you have a sequence on your database named ``sequenceList``?

Comment: yes, i have, SqlQueryRaw method  is what i needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, using `ExecuteRaw` I was able to get it:

```
var query = this.Database.SqlQueryRaw<int>($"Select {sequenceList}.NextVal From Dual ");
```